# Garbage collection None - del difference

Tags: python, collections, garbage

Is there any logical difference between `a = None` and `del a` in python?

The None keyword is used to define a null variable or an object. In python, None keyword is an object, and it is a data type of the class NoneType .

The del keyword is used to delete objects.

Are those identical to each other if I use the manual garbage collection?

Comment: `None` is a perfectly viable value. I'd be annoyed if the GC came along and scooped that up for me

Comment: "The del keyword is used to delete objects." **Absolutely incorrect**. Python provides no way to manage memory directly. `del` **deletes names/ references**, not objects.

Comment: "Are those identical to each other if I use the manual garbage collection?" What? Python uses reference counting as it's memory management strategy, you cannot deallocate an object explicitly, you can merely remove references. Once a reference count reaches 0, the object is **immediately reclaimed**. Reference cycles are handled by the cyclic garbage collector, which you can invoke manually using the `gc` module, but that isn't a typical thing.

Comment: What do you mean by "if I use the manual garbage collection"? What you describe is reference counting, which the CPython garbage collector does not influence. What PyPy does is not predictable with just a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `None` is still an object (of type `NoneType`) that takes memory and can be referenced whereas `del` deletes the object's name from the name space.

Say, you create a variable `a = None` in the global scope. It will exists in `globals()`. Now if you were to delete it with `del a`, the reference to `a` ceases to exist.

Comment: "del annihilates an object" no, it does not.

Comment: The correct way to phrase this is simply "`del` deletes a name".

Comment: "If there are no references to a, you may manually call a garbage collector with gc.collect which may free the object." is incorrect. Again, `a` *is the reference*. You are confusing references and objects.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to show the difference for yourself:

```
a = 5
a = None
print(a == 5)  
# False

del a
print(a == 5)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
# NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

in other words `a = None` still leaves the name `a` in your session. `del a` by contrast kills the name entirely and you'll get a `NameError` if you try to reference it.

Comment: "still leaves the object `a` in your session" `a` isn't an object, it's a *name*. del removes *names* not objects.

Comment: ok @juanpa.arrivillaga - I'll change it to name. But `a` is still an object as well. One that I assume get cleaned up after the name is removed. The original post said nothing about del removing the object, only the name, so I think it was correct as it was anway.

Comment: No, `a` is not an object, `a` **refers** to an object, but when you `del a` you are deleting the name `a`. Whether or not the object being referred to by `a` is reclaimed us up to the interpreter. The language Python only guarantees that as long as a reference exists to an object, it will not be garbage collected. The CPython implementation uses reference counting as it's memory management strategy, whereby objects are reclaimed immediately when their reference count reaches 0. Just by seeing a single line `del a` you cannot know, even in CPython, whether an object is reclaimed

Comment: And how would you refer to the object that the name `a` refers to if not by using its name?

Comment: Objects don't have "names". They can be referenced in many different ways; `a = object(); my_list = []; my_list.append(a); b = a;` there are now three different references to the object, one by `a`, one by `b` and one as an item in a list. If I `del a` nothing happens to the object except for it's reference count gets decremented by 1, however, 2 other references still exist, namely, the one in the list and `b`

Comment: Names are strings, strings are objects, so deleting a name deletes an object :-P

Comment: @StefanPochmann you can't even say that, because even in that particular case where a name is merely a `str` object in a `dict` (i.e., in the global scope), for example, `a = 2; del a` while the globals dictionary no longer contains an `'a'` key, in CPython, the `'a'` string is actually interned and exists for the duration of the python process... But we are talking here about language semantics, not implementation details.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I still don't see what's wrong with this answer as it stands. At no point did it ever say `del` removes the object.

Comment: You said "del a kills the object entirely" which is not true, and leads to misunderstandings that prop up all the time in endless questions about `del` and python's memory management. I've removed the download because you switched to the correct statement "kills the name"

Comment: I said "del a by contrast kills the name entirely"  - it always said that.